# Android Studio: Colgado al ejecutar una aplicación

Tags: android-studio

Durante más o menos 2 años estuve usando Eclipse ADT para desarrollar aplicaciones Android.

Luego de la noticia de que Google adoptó Android Studio como IDE oficial, pues no quedó otra que migrar.

Justo en estos momentos me está ocurriendo algo que me está fastidiando bastante.

## Android Studio 1.1

Mi entorno de trabajo es el siguiente:

1. Android Studio 1.1.0 (Feb, 2015) sé que está algo viejillo
2. Dispositivo real (teléfono) con Android 5.0.2
3. Equipo con 16GB de RAM y un Core i5

Android Studio y todo lo que ofrece vs Eclipse está genial, pero quienes venimos de trabajar con Eclipse percibimos ese "lentismo" que tiene esta herramienta.

No suficiente con eso, mi problema es que al ejecutar mi aplicación unas 2 o 3 veces va perfecto; al siguiente intento aparece lo siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y al momento de escribir este post lo he dejado allí para ver si llega  a hacer algo y esto es lo que lleva en ello

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**20 minutos!!!!** y no ejecuta nada y ni hablar de abortar la operación, porque se queda otros 20 minutos más!

Lo que tengo que hacer es abrir el administrador de tareas y finalizar el proceso, reiniciar el IDE; pero luego de los 2 o 3 intentos de ejecutar la app vuelve y se cuelga.

Para quienes lleven más tiempo trabajando con este IDE, ¿cómo puedo solventar este tipo de situaciones?

**Actualización**

Mencionar que la solución (aparentemente) ha sido una combinación de ambas respuestas suministradas por @Elenasys y @Ipman1971, realicé ambos ajustes sugeridos a nivel de Gradle y he trabajado sin problemas desde ayer en ambos equipos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Buena respuesta, buen rendimiento y ya no se cuelga ;) Recalco que aún sigo con la versión 1.1.0 en mi equipo de trabajo y la versión 1.5.1 y ambos, con esto; van mucho mejor, por ende descarto el asunto de que sea por temas de versión desactualizada. En otro momento de más confianza haré el update de versión.

## Android 2.2

Recién ahora actualicé la versión de Android Studio y ha sucedido lo mismo. En mi caso guardé los "Settings" de la versión anterior y los importé en esta nueva.

Particularmente uno de los settings rechazados fue el de colocar parámetros a la JVM de Gradle (respuesta que solventa el problema para la versión 1.1)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para la versión 2.+ no veo esta opción, en su lugar veo lo siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para la versión 2.+ ¿que parámetros deben ajustarse para evitar que el deploy de una app tarde o en algunos casos nunca se realice?

Comment: ¿ Existe algun motivo por el cual usted no a actualizado de version ?, creo que de ser posible es lo primero que tiene que hacer, pues parte de su pregunta son criticas hacia este IDE y quizas algunas de ellas se solventen con actualizar a  2.x. Saludos

Comment: Para mí es indeterminante, el equipo objeto de la pregunta es el de mi trabajo, mi equipo personal cuenta con la versión 1.5.1 (Dic 2015) y pasa exactamente lo mismo, por eso posteo la pregunta.

Comment: Rosendo tus dos equipos estan en la misma red? o fallan con un mismo proyecto?

Comment: El equipo de mi trabajo está detras de un Proxy el cual he configurado y funciona perfectamente, mi equipo personal está en mi casa con una red casera como cualquiera. Los proyectos son distintos. Como comento en la pregunta es tema de percepción y el defecto en particular que estamos cuestionando. Recalco que los proyectos se ejecutan bien, pero solo las primeras veces, luego de eso se cuelga y no despliega los apps

Answer (score 3):

Pueden ser diversos factores.

- Tienes una versión algo antigua, Android Studio 1.1.0 (Feb, 2015) 
  Primeramente te recomendaría actualizar, tal vez se tiene un problema con el ADT o aún con la versión de Gradle que utiliza.
- Te encuentras dentro de un proxy y no se tienen los permisos suficientes. Por lo tanto no puede descargar las dependencias definidas en tu `build.gradle`. Esto también se puede experimentar usando "IntelliJ Idea").
- Si las dependencias se descargaron puedes habilitar el modo "Offline work":

`File` > `Settings` > `Build, Execution, Deployment` > `Build Tools` > `Gradle`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: @RosendoRopher En adicion a esta repuesta, si usted esta usando algo similar a esto -> com.google.android.gms:play-services, usted puede mirar este link para seleccionar solo las que necesite -> https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#add_google_play_services_to_your_project Saludos

Comment: He actualizado la versión del software y ha sucedido lo mismo colega.

Answer (score 2):

Prueba con

```
Ctrl + Alt + S -> Compiler -> Gradle
```

Y en **VM Options** aumenta los valores, por ejemplo a

```
-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m
```

Comment: He actualizado la versión del software y ha sucedido lo mismo colega.

Answer (score 2):

Puede que todos esos problemas que tienes se solventan en actualizar a la [versión 2.0](http://tools.android.com/download/studio/builds/2-0), que ha llovido bastante en estabilidad y rendimiento.
Pero vigila en importar la configuración que tienes establecida que puede ser el causante, cómo te han indicado configura `Gradle` en que se use por defecto.