# Scanner Código de Barras

Tags: android, scanner, qr, código-de-barras, librería

estoy implementando a mi App un lector de código de barras QR y para ello necesito complementar la libreria, cosa que me está generando error, eh intentado con varias versiones pero nada aún, ya no se que hacer.

1.- Primero probé con:

compile 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.8.4'

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

** A lo que le cambie el "compile"por un "implementation"
y no me muestra este error pero nada sale nada de comentario, solo lo marca en rojo y ahi queda:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
2.-luego:

implementation 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9.0'

**Y el error es este:
Failed to resolve: me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9.0
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

*Ayuda Por favor, lo necesito con urgencia :( *

Comment: Actualiza la libreria a la ultima version para corregir los errores en el momento de compilacion, de acuerdo al 
[github](https://github.com/dm77/barcodescanner) la ultima version es: `implementation 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9.8'`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

a mi me funciona:

```
compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.0.2@aar'
compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.0'
```

Comment: journeyapps:zxing es diferente a barcodescanner de zxing

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda :)

Answer (score 1):

Primero asegura tengas conexión a internet y que no tengas activado el modo offline ya que esto no permitirá descargar la dependencia de ZXing:

[Android Studio: Colgado al ejecutar una aplicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/7995/android-studio-colgado-al-ejecutar-una-aplicaci%C3%B3n/7999#7999)

Si lo anterior es correcto entonces el problema es la library de soporte que usas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

te sugiero uses como máximo alguna de estas 3 opciones:

```
 implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
 implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
 implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
```

ya que posiblemente esta versión de ZXing (`'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9.0'` ) no esta preparada para trabajar con :

```
 implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc01'
```