# Android Studio no está descargando para trabajar offline

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

llevo tiempo con un proyecto y de buenas a primeras el Android Studio no me compila si no esta online.
Ya lo sincronize y compile online al menos una vez. Antes lo hacia y luego podia estar offline y compilaba de igual manera.

Tengo descargado el gradle-5.6.4 para trabajar con el offline y antes me funcionaba

**Estas son las dependencias de mi build.gradle**

```
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.1.0"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.1.0"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.1.0"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.1.0"
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:common-java8:2.1.0"
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
implementation 'androidx.paging:paging-runtime:2.1.0'
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:5.2.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.8.1'
implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.5.0")
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:okhttp3-integration:4.11.0'
implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:6.0.0'
implementation 'com.github.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.2'
implementation 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:2.0.0'
implementation "ch.acra:acra-mail:$acra_version"
implementation "ch.acra:acra-http:$acra_version"
implementation "ch.acra:acra-toast:$acra_version"
implementation "ch.acra:acra-dialog:$acra_version"
implementation 'me.pushy:sdk:1.0.53'
implementation 'com.cometchat:pro-android-chat-sdk:2.0.3'
implementation 'com.facebook.shimmer:shimmer:0.4.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
```

**Este es el error q me da**

```
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * What went wrong:
    Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
    > Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
       > Could not resolve com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.+.
         Required by:
             project :app > com.cometchat:pro-android-chat-sdk:2.0.3
          > No cached version listing for com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.+ available for offline mode.
          > No cached version listing for com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.+ available for offline mode.
          > No cached version listing for com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.+ available for offline mode.
          > No cached version listing for com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.+ available for offline mode.
          > No cached version listing for com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.+ available for offline mode.
       > Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:[15.0.1,16.0.0).
         Required by:
             project :app > com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1
          > No cached version listing for com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:[15.0.1,16.0.0) available for offline mode.
          > No cached version listing for com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:[15.0.1,16.0.0) available for offline mode.
          > No cached version listing for com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:[15.0.1,16.0.0) available for offline mode.
          > No cached version listing for com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:[15.0.1,16.0.0) available for offline mode.
          > No cached version listing for com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:[15.0.1,16.0.0) available for offline mode.
       > Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1,16.0.0).
         Required by:
             project :app > com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1
             project :app > com.google.android.gms:play-services-places-placereport:15.0.1
          > No cached version listing for com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1,16.0.0) available for offline mode.
          > No cached version listing for com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1,16.0.0) available for offline mode.
          > No cached version listing for com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1,16.0.0) available for offline mode.
          > No cached version listing for com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1,16.0.0) available for offline mode.
          > No cached version listing for com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1,16.0.0) available for offline mode.
       > Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:[15.0.1,16.0.0).
         Required by:
             project :app > com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1
          > No cached version listing for com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:[15.0.1,16.0.0) available for offline mode.
          > No cached version listing for com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:[15.0.1,16.0.0) available for offline mode.
          > No cached version listing for com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:[15.0.1,16.0.0) available for offline mode.
          > No cached version listing for com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:[15.0.1,16.0.0) available for offline mode.
          > No cached version listing for com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:[15.0.1,16.0.0) available for offline mode.
```

Cualquier ayuda la agradecería

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Estoy viendo errores de play services, estás seguro de que los tienes instalados?

Comment: me explicas? como instalados? adicionados en las dependencias?

Comment: En Android Studio, fuera del proyecto, en el SDK Manager, hay un apartado llamado SDK Platforms, te muestra las versiones que tienes de Android y todas las que puedes descargar, en el apartado SDK Tools puedes ver qué otras cosas tienes o puedes descargar, entre ellas se encuentra Google Play services

Comment: todo actualizado y lo mismo sigue pasando :( q puedo hacer ?

Comment: En el peor de los casos puedes intentar crear un nuevo proyecto y pasar el código de uno a otros. A veces es la mejor forma de arreglar errores a los que no les encuentras explicación

Comment: Se me ocurre que tal vez te estén faltando dependencias adicionales. Añade las que te dice. `com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp`, `com.google.android.gms:play-services-base`, `com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement` y `com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks`. En alguna de las versiones que te dice. Usa la misma versión para todas las de Google si están disponibles. Si te funciona dime y lo añado como respuesta.

Comment: 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.+', 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.1',  'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:15.0.1', 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:15.0.1'                      resolvio en parte las dependencias solo queda la del okhttp q aun da palo

Comment: ahora descargue los jar, de okhttp3 : 3.12.11 y los puse en la carpeta de libs y nada de offline, la cosa viene por la dependencia del comet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente encontré la solución, o bueno me ayudaron a encontrarla

lo q hice fue en el
*build.greadle*

```
android{
    ...
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
            if (details.requested.group == 'com.squareup.okhttp3') {
                details.useVersion '3.12.+'
                details.because 'just becasuse :D'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

y listo hiso la magia
https://github.com/cometchat-pro/android-chat-sdk/issues/28

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio puede trabajar offline, pero debes activar la conexiòn a internet en estos casos:

- Cuando agregas una nueva dependencia.
- Cuando deseas descargar una actualizaciòn.

**En este caso estas definiendo dependencias las cuales necesitas descargar** y son necesarias para crear tu proyecto:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> ```
> * What went wrong:
> Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> > Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
>    > Could not resolve com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.+.
>      Required by:
>          project :app > com.cometchat:pro-android-chat-sdk:2.0.3
>          **No cached version listing for com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.+ available for offline mode.**
> ```

Revisando la configuraciòn que tienes no estas haciendo uso de la dependencia directamente, lo que sucede es que alguna de las dependencias necesita las dependencias que no tienen version en cachè, agrega en tu `build.gradle` la definiciòn de las dependencias, por ejemplo:

```
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.+'
```

asegura deshabilitar el modo "Offline work" :

https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/7999/95

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: todo esta como dices, de hecho con un android studio posterior al de la foto. Previamente(con la misma versión de Android Studio) me funcionaba bien, al actualizar e incluir la dependencia del comet es q me viene dando ese problema